# Compile time check for quotient ring type in Rust

Tags: types, rust

I am learning Rust and I want to implement a type for quotient ring, for example integers modulo `m`. Here is what I have for `ops::Add`:

```
use std::ops;

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
struct Quot<T: ops::Add> {
    v: T,
    m: T,
}

impl<T> ops::Add for &Quot<T>
where
    T: ops::Rem<Output = T> + ops::Add<Output = T> + Copy + Eq,
{
    type Output = Quot<T>;

    fn add(self, other: Self) -> Self::Output {
        if self.m != other.m {
            panic!("Operation on elements from different rings");
        }
        Quot {
            v: (self.v + other.v) % self.m,
            m: self.m,
        }
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    let x = &Quot { v: 12, m: 19 };
    let y = &Quot { v: 10, m: 19 };
    let z = &Quot { v: 5, m: 7 };

    println!("{:?}", x + y); // ok
    println!("{:?}", x + z); // panic
}
```

As you can see, I have to do a check in runtime whether a modulo of two variables (Quot.m) is the same, and panic if it is not. Is it possible check that their type is the same in compile time? Semantically, I want something like

```
    type m = 19;
    type n = 7;
    let x = &Quot<m> { v: 12 };
    let y = &Quot<m> { v: 10 };
    let z = &Quot<n> { v: 5 };

    println!("{:?}", x + y); // ok
    println!("{:?}", x + z); // Compilation error
```

somewhat similar to `template<auto n>` in C++.

Answer (score 0):

In nightly, `generic_const_exprs` feature enables const operations.

In the following snippet, this features is required to evaluate the where clause `ConstCheck<{ M == N }>: True,`

You can adapt the code from this snippet. it should also work in your specific case.

```rust
#![feature(generic_const_exprs)]

pub struct ConstCheck<const CHECK: bool>;

pub trait True {}
impl True for ConstCheck<true> {}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Operand<const N: usize> {
    pub value: u8,
}

impl<const N: usize> Operand<N> {
    fn operator<const M: usize>(&self, other: Operand<M>) -> u8
    where
        ConstCheck<{ M == N }>: True,
    {
        self.value - other.value
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = Operand::<14>{value: 8};
    let b = Operand::<14>{value: 4};
    let c = Operand::<14>{value: 17};
    let d = Operand::<1>{value: 12};
    
    let res1 = a.operator(b); // OK
    let res2 = c.operator(d); // ERROR
}
```

At compilation time, `M == N` evaluates to true or false.

- If true, the resulting type is `ConstCheck<true>` which implements the trait True and so verifies the bound trait `ConstCheck<{ M == N }>: True` associated with the function operator.
- if false, the resulting type is `ConstCheck<false>` which doesn't implement the trait True and so doesn't verify the bound trait `ConstCheck<{ M == N }>: True` associated with the function operator.

Comment: Here I run into the same issue as with the other answer. You specify type of M,N to be usize. I wonder if it is possible to compare two constants of generic type T?

Comment: you want a custom type as your const generic instead of usize ?

Comment: Yes. I suppose, what I really want is dependent types, but for this specific case there might be some sort of workaround without them.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `const`-generics:

```
use std::ops;

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
struct Quot<T: ops::Add, const M: usize> {
    v: T,
}

impl<T, const M: usize> ops::Add for &Quot<T, M>
where
    T: ops::Rem<Output = T> + ops::Add<Output = T> + Copy + Eq + From<usize>,
{
    type Output = Quot<T, M>;

    fn add(self, other: Self) -> Self::Output {
        Quot {
            v: (self.v + other.v) % M.into(),
        }
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    let x = &Quot::<_, 19> { v: 12, };
    let y = &Quot::<_, 19> { v: 10, };
    let z = &Quot::<_, 7> { v: 5, };

    println!("{:?}", x + y); // ok
    // println!("{:?}", x + z); // error: expected `19_usize`, found `7_usize`
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d8dadd68495210b9459aaf7c2498b731)

Comment: There is a issue with such approach, namely `const M: usize`. Here I want M  to be of type T (maybe polynomial, or some sort of big int), and, well, "error[E0770]: the type of const parameters must not depend on other generic parameters"